# PHP/SQL: How to concatenate/combine columns value into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, concatenation

I have this php script called title, where it is supposed to list movie details of those movies with the title matching the inputed substring. The expected output is supposed to be like in the link/picture below. I have trouble with concatenating the genres of each movies since one movie can have many genres. I have tried using the concat(), array_to_string() but still fails.

> mkSQL() constructs "safe" SQL query strings by taking a query template
> string and filling in printf-like slots in the template with values
> supplied in subsequent arguments. The function takes a variable number
> of arguments; the first is always a query template string, with the
> following arguments corresponding exactly to the slots in the
> template. E.g.
>
> ```
>   $id = 3012345;  
>   $q1 = mkSQL("select * from R where id = %d",$id);
> ```
>
> would create the query strings:
>
> ```
>   $q1: "select * from R where id = 12345"
> ```

Below are the codes, any helps and tips will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

> This is the Genre Table Schema
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE Genre (
> movie_id integer REFERENCES Movie(id),
> genre GenreType,
> primary key (movie_id,genre));
> ```

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// include the common PHP code file
require("a2.php");

$db = pg_connect("dbname=mydb");

// Check arguments
if (count($argv) < 2) exit("$usage\n");

// Get the return results
$val = $argv[1];
$q = "select m.title, m.year, m.content_rating, r.imdb_score, array_to_string(array(select g.genre FROM Genre g where g.movie_id = m.id),',')
     -- concat(select g.genre FROM Genre g where g.movie_id = m.id
      from Movie m JOIN Rating r ON r.movie_id = m.id
      where m.title ilike %p
      order by m.year, r.imdb_score desc, m.title asc";
$r = pg_query($db, mkSQL($q, $val));

// Iterate through the results and print
$i = 1;
while ($t = pg_fetch_array($r)) {
  echo "$i. $t[0] ($t[1], $t[2], $t[3]) [$t[4]]\n";
  $i++;
}

?>
```

[The expected output is supposed to be in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDf1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like,

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.title, ' (', m.year, ', ', m.content_rating, ',', r.imdb_score, ') [', (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(g.genre), ',') FROM Genre g WHERE g.movie_id = m.id), ']') movie_title
FROM Movie m JOIN Rating r ON r.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.title ilike %p
ORDER BY m.year, r.imdb_score desc, m.title ASC
```

Here, I have concat all columns into one and given it an alias `movie_title`. You will get the movie name as per your specified format.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use PostgreSQL, is there an equivalent function of GROUP_CONCAT for PostgreSQL, or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this, you can use the group_concat function in your mysql script.
This will concatenate your respective column via comma(,).

Comment: Thanks but can't use group_concat() since I'm using postgre, but I found the answer using string_agg()